# TypeError: Cannot call method 'clone' of undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Jscript noob, so apologies as this is probably a silly question.

Trying to run some cloud code to clone an object. I don't understand why it is saying the object is undefined. All I wanted to do was copy an object without cycling through the members manually. The Bid object is valid and returned from a query.  I 'included' the creditTransaction on the query, so it was deep fetched.

```
  var bid = results[i];
  var oldCredit = bid.get("creditTransaction");
  var creditTransaction = oldCredit.clone();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am baffled, this is jQuery? or JS? or....

Comment: what does `console.log(results[i]);` tell you ?

Comment: @RobSedgwick it tells me I am an idiot... I have a nested query and I put the 'include' for creditTransaction in the wrong one.  Thanks!

Comment: @MobileVet, good stuff : )